# Saving a value in a variable does not work with crontab job but does work within Terminal

Tags: curl, cron

I want to save the value of this API-call to the variable OUTPUT1 with this crontab-job:

```
0/2 * * * * OUTPUT1=$(/usr/bin/curl -sSL "https://mempool.space/api/blocks/tip/height")
```

When I do echo $OUTPUT1 in the Terminal, the variable has no value.

When I do

```
OUTPUT1=$(/usr/bin/curl -sSL "https://mempool.space/api/blocks/tip/height")
```

in the Terminal window, the command echo $OUTPUT1 has the value that it should have.

Why is setting a value to $OUTPUT1 via crontab job not working in this case?

As stated above, I tried it with a crontab job, that does not work.

Doing it in the Terminal windows, it works.

Comment: You have to think about the parent - child relationships of processes. The `crontab` is the parent process to your cron entry. There is no reason for the (parent) cron process to have a `tty` associated with it, as this would defeat the idea of jobs running silently (in the back ground, etc from a schedule). By contrast, when you start a terminal session, there is automatically established a connection for the std-out to go to the terminal (a `tty`).  What would happen if all jobs running on a system where printing output a terminal? Very confusing and not helpful. ...

Comment: While any output from a job run from a crontab will be emailed to the cron users email account, many times it is not practical for a developer to see the cron output of a production level job, as a production level job should run with a production userid/password, unknown to a developer. What you CAN do is redirect your script's output to a file, so `0/2 * * * * { OUTPUT1=$(/usr/bin/curl -sSL "https://mempool.space/api/blocks/tip/height") ; echo $OUTPUT1 ; } > /tmp/myJobCronOutput.txt` is a basic solution to your question. But why you want to set an env var in the cron doesn't make sense IMHO.

Comment: There is more information about cron in the [tag:cron] tag that will help you understand. There are probably 100's of Q/A already here if you search for cron, so see what else you can find. Finally, please learn to format `code/data/output/Status-ErrMsgs/cronEntires` by mouse selecting the appropriate text and clicking the `{}` tool on the Edit menu to give correct `formatting`. Good luck.